# Traceroute with DSCP bits (QoS) with Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, traceroute, qos

Scapy allows the setting of DSCP or tos bits in IP packets, using the upper 6 bits of the 8 bit Type of Service field.

```
a = IP(dst="172.31.0.1", tos=184)
```

or

```
send(IP(dst="172.31.0.1")/ICMP())
```

It also permits traceroutes and modifications to the IP fields in traceroute.

```
ans,unans=sr(IP(dst="172.31.0.1", ttl=(4,25),id=RandShort())/TCP(flags=0x2))
```

Upon trying to enter tos bits into the traceroute, the packets generated appear to go to infinite recursion and requires a ctrl-c to stop the sending of packets.

```
 ans,unans=sr(IP(dst="172.31.0.1", ttl=(4,25),id=RandShort(), tos=184)/TCP(flags=0x2))
```

Has anyone found a way to get scapy to do dscp/tos with traceroute or sr()?

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't happen in the first `sr` example as well? i.e. even without setting the `tos` field?

Comment: Yes, the first example with sr works as planned.

Comment: Are you aware of the `timeout` argument (the full API may be found in the [official documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf))?